# Unable to resolve path to module './package.json' in React native application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, package, version-numbering

I am trying to get application version in my react native app.

To get app version, I have written following code.

```
import { version } from './package.json';


      console.log(version.appVersion);
```

But, It's throwing error like following

```
[eslint] Unable to resolve path to module './package.json'. [import/no-unresolved]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add your package.josn file?

Comment: Default package file, Can't show that data here

Comment: What is your project structure, is your package.json file in the same directory as the component you are importing from?

Comment: I have fixed is some syntax error in package.json

Answer (score -2):

I have fixed is some syntax error in package.json
Package.json data just check with https://jsonlint.com/ website wether it is valid json data or not.

I my case, There is one } symbol missed. So, Fixed. it.

Comment: Can u post the way you fixed it? I'm trying to get my version from the package.json but fails every time.